# Как преобразовать байты к word64 в Crypto++?

Tags: c++, криптография, преобразование-типов

Пытаюсь получить хеш от каких-либо данных с использованием Crypto++, однако функция `SHA512::Transform` принимает данные типа `word64`, что является синонимом типа `unsigned long long`, а мои данные представлены массивом `char`.

Вопрос: есть ли в этой библиотеке встроенные функции для корректного преобразования из `char*` в `word64*` или всё-таки придётся писать вручную?

P.S. Документацию читал, но в ней нет ни единого примера, что очень неудобно и не даёт разобраться.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для получения хеша необходимо вызывать следующие функции:

1. `SHA512_Init`
2. `SHA512_Update` - один или несколько раз, передавая данные как раз через указатель на `uint8_t const`
3. `SHA512_Final` - для получения хеша

`SHA512_Transform` использовать не следует, эта функция выполняет непосредственно алгоритм одного раунда вычисления.

Comment: То есть Update принимает как раз входные данные?

Comment: @V-Mor Да, использовать необходимо именно эту функцию.